# Round Corners only on Top

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

So i am trying to give my image round corners in Imagemagick via PHP but i only want to do so on the top.

At the moment ive dot this down but it makes all 4 corners round, i just want the 2 on top to be rounded.

```
$cornerradius_x = 10;
$cornerradius_y = 10;
$profimage=new Imagick($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/"."ccfe7ae5710b8f416c6e01a9d9ad1931.jpeg");
$profimage->readImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/"."ccfe7ae5710b8f416c6e01a9d9ad1931.jpeg");
$profimage->roundCorners($cornerradius_x,$cornerradius_y);
$profimage->writeImage("image.png");
```

Whats the best way to go about cornering on the top left and top right?

Comment: you will probably have to apply it to a secondary image resource then merge the two images together to get the desired output.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking that, i guess ill try it with that method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So i went ahead and split the image into two, the top half i rounded the corners on top, and the bottom half i just added to the bottom of the top half!